# No module named email_preprocess error when using Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am currently experiencing some difficulties with using Atom to run my python code, that otherwise works when launched through the command prompt. For those unfamiliar with Udacity's Introduction to Machine Learning, the "email preprocess" module is located in "...\naive_bayes\tools" directory.

Code:

```
import sys
from time import time
sys.path.append("../tools/")
from email_preprocess import preprocess
```

Whenever i run the 
**nb_author_id.py** file through the command prompt with the following command:

```
python2 nb_author_id.py
```

in the **D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\ud120-projects-master\naive_bayes** directory, it works fine. But, if want to run the **nb_author_id.py** file through Atom (using atom-runner) I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\ud120-projects-master\naive_bayes\nb_author_id.py", line 17, in <module>
    from email_preprocess import preprocess
ImportError: No module named email_preprocess
```

Any ideas why it works through the command prompt, but not through Atom?

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to use relative paths in `sys.path`. You never know what the current directory will be when your program runs. Most likely, when running from Atom, your current directory is NOT where it was when you ran from the command line.

If you need to locate a module relative to the directory where the module from which you are trying to import it, try these methods (in the order listed) to find it and add it to sys.path:

- `myfile = globals().get("__file__")` (this will work from an imported module or from your main program if it was loaded via an IDE or in any other way except directly from the command line). If this returns a value, add `os.path.dirnme(myfile)` (or a derivative of it, as needed) to your path.
- `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` (this works only for your main module)

Comment: If it is best not to use relative paths in sys.path, shouldn't something like sys.path.append("D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\ud120-projects-master\naive_bayes\tools") work?

Comment: Yes, that would work, of course. It does limit your code to the specific location you've chosen on your host - but if that's the only place where you'd run it, that's OK.

Comment: If i use sys.path.append("D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\ud120-projects-master\naive_bayes\tools")  I still get the same error. No idea why :c

Comment: If you use that **literally**, it will not work because the \ characters get eaten. Either double them, or use the "raw" string literal: `r"D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\..."` (this form preserves \ as-is).

Comment: Neither sys.path.append("D:\\Misiek\\Pulpit\\python\\ud120-projects-master\\naive_bayes\\tools")  or  sys.path.append(r"D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\ud120-projects-master\naive_bayes\tools")  have worked. :(

Comment: I am using Windows 10, in case it matters.

Comment: Maybe it's the wrong directory - check the exact place where your 'email_preprocess' module is located.

Answer (score 0):

Add that directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable, so that it doesn't have to be imported from the same directory. Append that directory to the end by adding `D:\Misiek\Pulpit\python\ud120-projects-master\naive_bayes;`

[image: Editing System PYTHONPATH]